# Break up a SQL Server 2008 query into batches

Tags: sql-server-2008, batch-processing

I'm trying to prepare some data for deletion by a 3rd party, and unfortunately they can only process data in batches of 2000 records.  I have 100k records and may need to divide-and-export this data several more times, so I'd like to automate the process somehow.

Is there a reasonably easy way to do this using SQL Server 2008?  I'm not running a complex query -- it's not too far off from `SELECT PKID FROM Sometable ORDER BY PKID` -- and while I can probably do this using a cursor, I'd like to know if there's a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SyncAudit] ( PkId INT, BatchNumber INT)

DECLARE  @batchsize INT
    ,@rowcount INT
    ,@batchcount INT
    ,@rootdir VARCHAR(2048)
    ,@saveas VARCHAR(2048)
    ,@query VARCHAR(2048)
    ,@bcpquery VARCHAR(2048)
    ,@bcpconn VARCHAR(64)
    ,@bcpdelim VARCHAR(2)

SET     @rootdir    = '\\SERVER1\SHARE1\FOLDER\'
SET     @batchsize  = 2000
SET     @bcpdelim   = '|'
SET     @bcpconn    = '-T' -- Trusted
--SET       @bcpconn    = '-U <username> -P <password>' -- SQL authentication

SELECT  @rowcount   = COUNT(1),
    @batchcount = CEILING(COUNT(1)/@batchsize) FROM <@TableName, string, 'SomeTable'>

SELECT [BatchSize] = @BatchSize, [BatchCount] = @Batchcount

INSERT INTO SyncAudit
SELECT 
 <@TableKey, string, 'PKField'>
 ,groupnum = NTILE(@batchcount) OVER ( ORDER BY <@TableKey, string, 'PKField'>)
FROM
<@TableName, string, 'SomeTable'>

WHILE (@batchcount > 0)
BEGIN

SET @saveas = @rootdir + 'batchnumber-' + cast(@batchcount as varchar) + '.txt'
SET @query = '  SELECT  [<@TableName, string, 'SomeTable'>].* 
                FROM    [' + db_name() + '].[dbo].[<@TableName, string, 'SomeTable'>] 
                JOIN    [' + db_name() + '].[dbo].[SyncAudit]   
                            ON  [<@TableName, string, 'SomeTable'>].<@TableKey, string, 'PKField'> = [SyncAudit].PkId 
                            AND [SyncAudit].BatchNumber = ' + cast(@batchcount as varchar) + ''

SET @bcpquery = 'bcp "' + replace(@query, char(10), '') + '" QUERYOUT "' + @saveas + '" -c -t^' + @bcpdelim + ' ' + @bcpconn + ' -S ' + @@servername
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpquery  

--EXEC (@query)


SET @batchcount = @batchcount -1
END


DROP TABLE [dbo].[SyncAudit] -- or leave for reference
```

Comment: Very interesting -- the fact that it exports directly to a file is especially nice.  I haven't had a chance to try it out yet, but I'll give it a shot this afternoon.  tyvm!

Answer (score 4):

I think you can take advantage of using ROW_NUMBER and then using BETWEEN to specify a range of rows that you like. Alternatively you could use PKID if you knew there wasn't gaps, or didn't care about the gaps

e.g.

```
SELECT ...
FROM
   (SELECT ... 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PKID ) as RowNum
    FROM Sometable e
   ) t
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @startRowIndex AND (@startRowIndex + @maximumRows) - 1
```

This is often used for paging results. 4GuysFromRolla have a good [article on it](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140032/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031506-1.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, this is the direction I was going to head in, in the absence of a more elegant solution.  However, I don't have much experience working with ROW_NUMBER(), so your example is still quite helpful.  :)

Comment: Would row_number() progressively get slower the further in the range it gets? Esp near the end of the 100k records

Answer (score 3):

You could work out the ranges in a while @@ROWCOUNT loop to target the rows required. It may work better than ROW_NUMBER() which would have to keep numbering from the start.

```
declare @startid int
declare @endid int

-- get one range, these are efficient as they go over the PKID key by range
select top(1) @startid = pkid from sometable order by pkid  -- 1 key visited
select top(2000) @endid = pkid from sometable order by pkid  -- 2000 keys visited
-- note: top 2000 may end up with the 514th id if that is the last one

while @@ROWCOUNT > 0
begin
    insert otherdb.dbo.backupcopy
    select * from sometable
    where pkid between @startid and @endid

    select top(1) @startid = pkid from sometable
    WHERE pkid > @endid -- binary locate
    order by pkid

    select top(2000) @endid = pkid from sometable
    WHERE pkid > @endid -- binary locate, then forward range lookup, max 2000 keys
    order by pkid
end
```

Comment: This looks great -- I may try combining it with Adam's post to export the output directly to text files.  However, I'm not understanding the following comment: "note: top 2000 may end up with the 514th id if that is the last one".  Could you explain?

Comment: Even though you ask for top(2000), if there are only 514 records (left), then the last record is the 514th. An assignment in a multirow select works by assigning to the value of the last row, so @endid=pkid is assigned to the id of the 514th row (last) if there aren't 2000 rows.

Comment: ohh, I see -- you just mean that's how you deal with cases where the last batch doesn't contain exactly 2000 rows, right?

Comment: @AspNyc - exactly. The "first" batch could also be the "last" batch.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a combination of the approaches provided by **cyberkiwi** and **Adam**.  I didn't need to use `ROW_NUMBER` only because I used an `IDENTITY` column in a `table` data type instead.

Here's a redacted version of the code I used -- it worked like a charm.  Thanks again to everyone for all the help!

```
use Testing
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON

declare
    @now datetime = GETDATE(), 
    @batchsize int = 2000, 
    @bcpTargetDir varchar(500) = '\\SomeServer\Upload\', 
    @csvQueryServer varchar(500) = '.\SQLExpress', 
    
    @rowcount integer, 
    @nowstring varchar(100), 
    @batch_id int, 
    @startid int, 
    @endid int, 
    @oidCSV varchar(max), 
    @csvQuery varchar(max), 
    @bcpFilename varchar(200), 
    @bcpQuery varchar(1000)
    
declare @tblBatchRanges table (
    batch_id integer NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    oid_start integer NOT NULL, 
    oid_end integer NOT NULL, 
    csvQuery varchar(max)
)

-- Create a unique timestamp-based string, which will be used to name the exported files.
select @nowstring = CONVERT(varchar, @now, 112) + '-' + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, @now, 114), ':', '')


-- 
select top(1) @startid = oid from Testing..MyObjectIds order by oid
select top(@batchsize) @endid = oid from Testing..MyObjectIds order by oid
select @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT

while (@rowcount > 0) begin
    -- Create a CSV of all object IDs in the batch, using the STUFF() function
    select @csvQuery = 'select stuff((select distinct '','' + CAST(oid as varchar) from Testing..MyObjectIds where oid between ' + CAST(@startid as varchar) + ' and ' + CAST(@endid as varchar) + ' order by '','' + CAST(oid as varchar) for xml path('''')),1,1,'''')'


    -- Log the info and get the batch ID.   
    insert into @tblBatchRanges (oid_start, oid_end, csvQuery)
        values (@startid, @endid, @oidCSV, @csvQuery)
        
    select @batch_id = @@IDENTITY


    -- Advance @startid and @endid so that they point to the next batch
    select top(1) @startid = oid 
        from Testing..MyObjectIds
        where oid > @endid
        order by oid

    select top(@batchsize) @endid = oid 
        from Testing..MyObjectIds
        where oid > @endid
        order by oid
        
    select @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT

    
    -- Export the current batch to a file.
    select @bcpFilename = 'MyExport-' + @nowstring + '-' + cast(@batch_id as varchar) + '.txt'
    select @bcpQuery = 'bcp "' + @csvQuery + '" QUERYOUT "' + @bcpTargetDir + @bcpFilename + '" -S ' + @csvQueryServer + ' -T -c'
    exec master..xp_cmdshell @bcpquery
end

SET NOCOUNT OFF


--Check all of the logged info.
select oid_start, oid_end, csvQuery from @tblBatchRanges
```