# Add row to 'Break up a SQL Server 2008 query into batches'

Tags: sql, export, batch-processing, bcp

I was successful in exporting to a flat file using bcp with the help of [Break up a SQL Server 2008 query into batches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729697/break-up-a-sql-server-2008-query-into-batches/15645434#15645434).

Now I would like to add one (or two) rows to each batch. This is needed to "offset" the total $ amount so each batch will balance to zero. For example, I have 2,501 records in a table. 2,500 have an amount of $100 and are all booked to account # 70000 so that totals $250,000. The last record, #2,501, is booked to account # 80000 and its value is ($250,000); therefore the total table balances.

Since our new system will only allow batches up to 950 rows, I have to split the output using the above link's code. Works great, BTW. But since each batch has to "balance" to zero, I need to add one row in each batch, and set that to the offset account (#80000, for example).

I hope that makes sense to someone! ;-] Suggestions on where/when to insert the record, and can I insert it after each batch is created, or before?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should insert the new record after each batch is created. And, one more suggestion, the post you linked is using 'insert into table...select...', it is slower than 'select ... into table'. And 'select into table' will automatically create table for you. After each batch bcp out successfully, you can drop the table automatically created. You can also have a history table to remember what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is what I came up with following Ijh's suggestion and code I 'lifted' from the previously linked post :

```
-- Set up some variables 
declare
@batchsize      int = 900, 
@bcpTargetDir   varchar(10) = 'c:\tempFolder\', 
@csvQueryServer varchar(15) = 'SQLserverName', 
@rowcount       integer, 
@nowstring      varchar(25), 
@group          varchar(25),
@batch_id       int, 
@startID        int, 
@endID          int, 
@oidCSV         varchar(max), 
@csvQuery       varchar(max), 
@bcpFilename    varchar(25), 
@bcpQuery       varchar(1000)

-- create the Batch Range temp table
declare @tblBatchRanges table (
batch_id        integer NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
oid_start       integer NOT NULL, 
oid_end         integer NOT NULL, 
csvQuery        varchar(max)
)

-- Create a unique datestamp-based string, which will be used to name the exported files.
select @nowstring = REPLACE(CONVERT(char(8),GETDATE(),1),'/','-')

-- Set the value of @startid
select top(1) @startID = jeDataID 
    from DBname.dbo.tableName
    where groupReference = @group
    order by jeDataID

-- Set the value of @endid
select top(@batchsize) @endID = jeDataID 
    from DBname.dbo.tableName 
    where groupReference = @group
    order by jeDataID

select @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT

-- create temp table to hold each batch --------------
CREATE TABLE ##jeDataTemp
(
jeDataID int,
docDate date,
GLacct varchar(17),
amount decimal(13, 2),
groupReference varchar(25) 
)

-- ===================================================
-- Loop through the data with a WHILE loop

WHILE (@rowcount > 0) begin

-- since I'm using a temp table to hold the data,
-- I need to clear it out each Loop through
truncate table ##jeDataTemp

-- insert the data into the temp table using the start and end ID values
insert into ##jeDataTemp
(jeDataID, docDate, GLacct, amount, groupReference)

select jeDataID, docDate, GLacct, amount, groupReference 
from tableName 
where jeDataID between @startID and @endID
order by jeDataID

-- insert the General Ledger offset to a different GL acct #
-- by getting the SUM of the [amount] field * -1
insert into ##jeDataTemp
(docDate, GLacct, amount, groupReference)

Select  max(docDate), 
        '8000000'   as GLacct,
        SUM(##jeDataTemp.amount)*-1 as amount,
        @group

from ##jeDataTemp

-- create the select statement with the ID parameters for each file to be exported
select @csvQuery = 'select * from ##jeDataTemp order by jeDataID'

-- Log the info and get the batch ID.  
insert into @tblBatchRanges (oid_start, oid_end, csvQuery)
    values (@startID, @endID, @csvQuery)

select @batch_id = @@IDENTITY

-- Advance @startid and @endid so that they point to the next batch
-- and filter for the selected Group Reference
select top(1) @startID = jeDataID
    from tableName
    where jeDataID > @endID
  AND groupReference = @group
    order by jeDataID

select top(@batchsize) @endID = jeDataID 
    from tableName
    where jeDataID > @endID
  AND groupReference = @group
    order by jeDataID

-- set the row count variable value
select @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT

-- Export the current batch to a file. ---------------
-- Set the file name with the current Date and Batch ID #
select @bcpFilename = 'JE_' + @nowstring + '-' + cast(@batch_id as varchar) + '.txt'

select @bcpQuery = 'bcp "' + @csvQuery + '" QUERYOUT "' + 
            @bcpTargetDir + @bcpFilename + '" -S ' + @csvQueryServer + ' -T -c '
exec master..xp_cmdshell @bcpQuery

-- end the WHILE loop
END    

-- drop the temp table
drop table ##jeDataTemp
```

Sure hope this helps someone else out along the way!
Sean