# sql query jobs for top records while iterating

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with huge records in sql.(I have a procedure which displays top 100) How do i iterate through the whole records and display first 100 and then the next 100 and so on in a loop. ie
Process in batches of 100. An external query or process can execute this procedure in a loop

Comment: Definition of table including indexes? Desired processing order? Why do you need to process in batches? What type of processing are you doing?

Comment: You mean in C#, for example ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Break up a SQL Server 2008 query into batches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729697/break-up-a-sql-server-2008-query-into-batches)

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you could use the `SqlDataReader`class. With this, you can read through all records, row by row.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass two parameters offset and limit to SP. Then keep limit to 100 and add the 100 in offset every time you execute the SP.

Starting value of offset is zero.

Comment: how would i exclude the previous 100 in this case.

Comment: when offset is 0 and limit is 100 then you will get the first 100 records. Next time add limit to offset now offset it 100 and limit is 100 now you will exclude the previous 100. Keep on adding the limit in offset till the last records.

Answer (score 0):

i want to get records from 0 - 100 first time, next time 101 - 200 . Im thinking of cursors to open whole records and then select top 100 where id deos not exist in the temp table and insert the unique id into temp table.